# Change source ip of an incoming packet at the same interface and how to see it?

Tags: networking, iptables, ip

I have one application running on Server B which listens to eth0 on Server B.

I have a GTP packet coming from Server A whose source address I want to change. 
And in the GTP layer in the packet, the public IP (which is x.x.x.x) is present. I want to change the src IP to x.x.x.x.

The application expects x.x.x.x series but in the header it gets 10.x.x.x, so it drops the packet and is unable to establish the connection.

> 10.x.x.x(src)---->x.x.x.x(dest)

I am aware that there are some solutions in the portal, but my issue is there is no outgoing interface, it's the application who is listening and replies back using the changed IP; i.e., x.x.x.x on eth0 only. And how can I see the packets? With `tcpdump`?

I have used a sample rule from the web, which is:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to x.x.x.x
```

But it doesn't serve my purpose.

Basically the packet is gtp and coming from a nated interface. And the packet consists of the public IP in gtp layer. The application is discarding the nated source IP as it looks for the public IP which is present inside the packet while connection request.If I can assign the public IP as src IP (which is reachable) then the connection will be established and outgoing traffic can also go via the modified src IP as a reply and eventually connection will be established.

Can I have an iptable rule that will change my src IP to the public IP present in the GTP layer when the packet comes to eth0?

Comment: Yes `tcpdump` or `wireshark` are two popular packet sniffers. You can also use the `-j LOG` target in iptables to debug. Why do you want to change the address?

Comment: Basically the packet is gtp and coming from a nated interface. And the packet consists of the public IP in gtp layer. The application is discarding the nated source IP as it looks for the public IP which is present inside the packet while connection request.If I can assign the public IP as src IP (which is reachable) then the connection will be established and outgoing traffic can also go via the modified src IP as a reply and hence connection will be established

Comment: Ok. Well, try to debug with the tools of the previous message. You should be able to edit your post so that it looks like a question. Try to be specific and add information on the problem (what you expect/what you get). The more relevant information you provide, the more likely you are to get some help.

Comment: Thanks!! I am new to Stackexchange. i have edited my post

Comment: iptables and conntrack can't do SNAT on ingress (PREROUTING) nor DNAT on egress (POSTROUTING): this rare case doesn't fit with the current netfilter layout.You should treat this as a routing problem with a tunnel context instead. If NAT is really really needed, other tools (tc or nftables) can do stateless nat. But it would probably bring additional issues. The [comment describing this tunnel context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596509/change-source-ip-of-an-incoming-packet-at-the-same-interface-and-how-to-see-it?noredirect=1#comment1113464_596509) should be added to the question.